# Checking Internet status on Splash screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am trying to make Alert Dialog Box when internet is not available  but I get error that cannot resolve method `setButton(java.lang.String, anonymous android.content.DialogInterface.On Click Listener)`
The error Shows after setting the OK button, I cannot see the problem but it is linked with `import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;`

Here is my splash activity code:

```
package com.SplashTest.mk;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        if(isWorkingInternetPersent()){
            splash();
        }
        else{
            showAlertDialog(SplashActivity.this, "No Internet!",
                    "It looks like you dont have intrenet connection", false);
        }
    }
    public void splash() {
        Thread timerTread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(4000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        timerTread.start();
    }
    public boolean isWorkingInternetPersent() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivityManager != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (NetworkInfo anInfo : info)
                    if (anInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }

        }
        return false;
    }
    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        // Setting alert dialog icon
        // alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.mipmap.ic_launcher : R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }}
```

Comment: Add your Logcat output, pasting some random blip of an error log isn't helpful.

Comment: error: no suitable method found for setButton(String,<anonymous OnClickListener>)
method AlertDialog.setButton(int,CharSequence,Message) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method AlertDialog.setButton(int,CharSequence,OnClickListener) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the first argument for the method. Try

```
alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
```